# validate date in a particular format using preconditions

Tags: java, date, preconditions

I have a date in string format `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` which I need to validate using preconditions google guava class. I am using `checkArgument` method in lot of other places. How can I use `checkArgument` method to validate `startDate` to make sure it is in this format only `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` and if they are not, then throw IllegalArgumentException with some message.

```
public Builder startDate(String startDate) {
    // validate startDate here using checkArgument if it is not valid then throw IllegalArgumentException.
    this.sDate = startDate;
    return this;
}
```

How can I use checkArgument method here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't.  Write

```
 try {
   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse(startDate);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
 }
```

..which will also let you store the `Date` parsed and use it later.  (Though, to be fair, `java.util.Date` is a terrible API best avoided -- but you implied you were using it in a previous question you appear to have deleted.)

If you end up using Joda Time, http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output explains how to adjust this answer for those needs.

Comment: Note that by default, `SimpleDateFormat` instances are _lenient_ w.r.t. parsing input strings. So, unless you want to allow date strings such as `2015/13/32 25:60:60` to parse correctly, you should call [`setLenient(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) on the `SimpleDateFormat` instance before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

[The Answer by Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688167/642706) is correct. He mentions avoiding the java.util.Date.

## java.time

That java.util.Date class, and its partner java.util.Calendar, have been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. See the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

We use [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [`DateTimeParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) classes instead. Contained in the [`java.time.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package.

Here is the equivalent of his Answer using java.time classes.

```
try {
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ).parse ( input );
} catch ( e ) {
    throw new DateTimeParseException ( e );
}
```

## Joda-Time

For those unable to move to Java 8 or later, add the Joda-Time library to your project. [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) provided the inspiration for java.time, and the two frameworks share the same concepts.

[Wasserman’s same logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688167/642706) applies to our solution: Make a parse attempt, and catch an exception. We use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class from Joda-Time which throws a standard Java [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) when encountering bad input.

```
try {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern ( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" );
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime ( input );
} catch ( e ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException ( e );
}
```

Comment: I am on Java 7 as of now so can't use Java 8. :(

Comment: @user1950349 I would strongly advise using third-party libraries like Joda Time over `java.util.Date` if you can _possibly_ manage it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I can manage that but then will it change anything in the parsing logic you have?

Comment: @user1950349, sure, you'll have to use Joda's APIs for that then.  http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output explains all the details there.

Comment: As Wasserman says, the old date-time classes really are so bad that they should be avoided. Add and use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library instead. In using Joda-Time, follow the same logic seen in Wasserman’s Answer: call on a date-time formatter instance to attempt a parse, and catch the parsing exception.

Comment: That sourceforge.net URL in the comment above is out of date. See the [Getting Started](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html) and [User Guide](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html) pages for Joda-Time. Joda-Time provided the inspiration for java.time, so by learning Joda-Time you will be learning the basic concepts that can be applied to mastering java.time later in the future.

Comment: @user1950349 Yes, bingo. I added that Answer’s code snippet to my Answer here in a new "Joda-Time" section.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the whole string against a regular expression:

```
Preconditions.checkArguments(str.matches(VALID_DATE_REGEX));
```

To speed things up, you can compile the Pattern once and invert the call

```
Preconditions.checkArgument(VALID_DATE_REGEX.matcher(str).matches());
```

However **this is a smell**. You should not carry this string of text back and forth in your program: if you need that format it's just because at some point you'll convert it to a date. So you'd better decide if your program can accept invalid input and reporting it to the user, or if it should terminate immediately.

The latter is easier to handle: parse the text immediately and throw an exception for invalid input. Otherwise you need to introduce a validation step in your program, and then program a way to stop the flow and showing the user any blocking and non-blocking errors in the input.